# php stripos чувствителен к регистру

Tags: php

```html
<?php
if (stripos('Вы', 'вы') !== false) echo '123';
```

Ничего не выводит. Почему?
`stripos` же не чувствителен к регистру

Comment: Потому что 0 это false. А также потому что для __многобайтных кодировок__ нужен `mb_stripos`.

Comment: Точно) Но в коде у меня было `!== false`, так что проблема не в этом

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, mb_stripos помог